# Selecting elements from a list under multiple conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

Suppose there is the following list:

```
l={{{3, 3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 
   1}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {3,
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}, {{3, 3, 3, 3}, {3, 3, 3, 2,
    1}, {3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 
   3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
   1}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
   2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

I want to select sublists that satisfy the following conditions:

1. Each sublist can at most have one `3`.
2. Each sublist can at most have three `2`s.
3. Each element can at most have three `1`s.

The following sublists would remain:

```
{{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

and the rest of sublists should be dropped. Is there a way to have more than one condition when selecting sublists from a nested list/array in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, a slightly more intricate approach using `Counts[]` is useful:

```
Select[(And @@ Thread[Lookup[Counts[#], {1, 2, 3}, 0] <= {3, 3, 1}]) &] /@ l
   {{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Pick[l, Map[Count[#, 3] < 2 && Count[#, 2] < 4 && Count[#, 1] < 4 &, 
l, {2}]]
```

> {{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}

Answer (score 6):

```
Pick[l, Map[VectorLessEqual[{BinCounts[#, {1/2, 3 + 1/2, 1}] , {3, 3, 1} }]&, l, {-2}] ]
```

> {{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}

Answer (score 3):

**Using `DeleteCases`:**

```
DeleteCases[l, {a___
  , OrderlessPatternSequence[
   Repeated[3, {2, ∞}] |
     Repeated[2, {4, ∞}] |
     Repeated[1, {4, ∞}]
   ]
  , b___
  }
 , {2}
 ]
```

> {{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}

Comment: (+1) Nice, @Syed!

Answer (score 2):

Using `GroupBy`, `Count` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[
    GroupBy[Join @@ l,
        Function[
            And[LessEqual[0, Count[#, 3], 1],
                    LessEqual[1, Count[#, 2], 3],
                    LessEqual[1, Count[#, 1], 3]
                ]
        ],
        Map[List, #] &
    ],
    True
 ]

(*{{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}*)
```

Or equivalently:

```
Lookup[
    Table[
        GroupBy[l[[i]],
            Function[
                    And[LessEqual[0, Count[#, 3], 1],
                        LessEqual[1, Count[#, 2], 3],
                        LessEqual[1, Count[#, 1], 3]
                    ]
                ]
        ],
        {i, 1, Length @l}
    ],
    True
 ]

 (*{{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}, {{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}}*)
```

Comment: The sublists must have at most one `3` meaning `0` or `1` entries. Perhaps you need a `LessEqual` there as well?

Comment: You're right Syed! Thanks for pointing that out. I'll correct it in a moment. :-)

Comment: I've been trying to keep up with your work rate about list manipulations, and it's really training me.

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest solution, but very readable (for me):

```
Extract[l,
 Position[{True ..}] @
  Query[All, All,
    {LessThan[2] @* Count[3],
     LessThan[4] @* Count[2],
     LessThan[4] @* Count[1]}] @ l]
```

{{3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}}